# Cylinder. OXYZ. 3D Cylinder . cylinder with dots

Tags: diagrams, graphs

i whant help with drowing cylinder in 3d  with dots(p1,p2,...pn) on both side cylinder [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Aren't you [this user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/186173/levan-davitadze) as well? The calligraphy is _very_ similar and the first name is the same.

Comment: yes i am.  i need to get this job done in 3 hours so i made another account becouse fist one was banned for 24 hours

Comment: If it was banned it's because you are not using this site as it's meant to be used. This is not a “do my assignment for me” service. We usually relax the rules for new users but you should learn from the answers you get, not keep posting pictures and asking people to do it for you. And trying to do it 3 hours before the deadline is a terrible idea. (It doesn't look like you were banned, though).

Comment: ya i understand that i should do  nice title whats wrong with that?. and i drow cylinder for my self but i cant  draw dots so asked for help. sorry if i am doing somthing wrong .

Comment: The problem is not the title, is that you are showing no effort and leaving all the work for other people. Now that you got answers to your questions the least you can do is show your appreciation by upvoting and accepting those answers. This post shows how you do that: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852

Comment: i up voted every one but its not scored becouse i dont have 15 reputation

Comment: @levan But you can still mark them as accepted.

Comment: I see no evidence that your previous account is suspended. You can ask stackexchange to merge the accounts see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{105}{-30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{1.5}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Height}{4}
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (2.5*\Radius,0,0) node[pos=1.05] {$x$};
 \draw[-stealth] (O) -- (0,2.5*\Radius,0) node[pos=1.05] {$y$};
 \draw[-stealth] (O) -- (0,0,1.25*\Height) node[pos=1.05] {$x$};
 \draw[dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180,smooth]
    ({\Radius+\Radius*cos(\x)},{\Radius*sin(\x)},0);
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]   
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {-2/3,-1/3,2/3}
  {\node[bullet,transform shape] (B-\Y) at (\Radius+\Radius*\X,0){};}
  \foreach \Y in {1,2,3}
  {\node[anchor=south] at (B-\Y){\ifnum\Y=3
  $P_n$
  \else
  $P_\Y$
  \fi};}
 \end{scope}
 \draw[left color=gray,right color=gray!80,middle color=gray!20,fill opacity=0.5]
  plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180,smooth]
   ({\Radius+\Radius*cos(\x)},{\Radius*sin(\x)},0)
   -- plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi+180:\tdplotmainphi,smooth]
   ({\Radius+\Radius*cos(\x)},{\Radius*sin(\x)},\Height) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\Height] 
  \fill[gray!30] (\Radius,0) circle[radius=\Radius];
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {-2/3,-1/3,2/3}
  {\node[bullet,transform shape] (T-\Y) at (\Radius+\Radius*\X,0){};}
  \foreach \Y in {1,2,3}
  {\node[anchor=south] at (T-\Y){\ifnum\Y=3
  $P_n$
  \else
  $P_\Y$
  \fi};}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: iits not my code i find code on this site and  i  did not khnow that it was needed i will try to ask better questions. sorry again.

Comment: thank u marmot  i will mention u when i solve knot recognition problem

Comment: @levan No need to mention and I removed the comments in my answer since you seem to have read them.